# Can I get url, that is generated by JavaScript, using Selenium and Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, parsing

I write parser using Selenium and Python 3.7 for next site - https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/nurnberg-dortmund-fNa2KmU4/

I'm interested, to get the url, that is generated by JavaScript, using Selenium in Python 3?

I need to get the url for events from the sites from which the data is taken in the table.

[image]

For example. It seems to me that the data in the first line (10Bet) is obtained from this page - https://www.10bet.com/sports/football/germany-1-bundesliga/20190218/nurnberg-vs-dortmund/

How can get url to this page?

Comment: What url you exactly want?

Comment: Sry... I need to get the url for events from the sites from which the data is taken in the table.

Comment: so is that u want to get the url of the link like 18bet / 1x bet in the table without clicking them?

Comment: I want to get the url of events in these offices (18bet/1xbet etc) without clicking on them. I'm updated description.

Comment: Looks like you can't get the direct url, as oddsportal has created a bookmark redirection for this, so the current option you have is to get the href attribute & add it with "https://www.oddsportal.com/" , which will then redirect to the underlying url of the actual site you are looking for

Comment: It's a pity. I know how to get the url to the site bookmark.

Comment: okies.. so going forward it would be great if you give as much as examples possible & the ones you tried in the first place so that it can help for quick resolution & save time

Comment: Ok. Thnx for help. I will take your wishes.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `URL` of all the links on a page, you can store all the elements with tagname `a` in a `WebElement` list and then you can fetch the `href` attribute to get the link of each `WebElement`.

you can refer to the following code for all the link present in hole page :

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); //This will store all the link WebElements into a list

    for(WebElement ele: links) // This way you can take the Url of each link
    {
    String url = ele.getAttribute("href"); //To get the link you can use getAttribute() method with "href" as an argument 
    System.out.println(url);
    }
```

In case you need the particilar link explicitly you need to pass the xpath of the element

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("Pass the xapth of the element"));
```

and after that you need to do this

```
String url = ele.getAttribute("href") //to get the url of the particular element
```

I have also shared the link with you so you can go and check i have highlighted elements in that

[image]

let us know if that helped or not

Comment: Thnx for answer. I know it. But this is not exactly. You offer links to the bookmaker's main page, иut the data comes from other pages of these sites (bookmakers). See example url in description.

Comment: But **@SnR** says that it’s impossible to get them.

Comment: its not like that

Comment: you can get but you should have that much knowledge about it

Comment: I'm understand(

Comment: sorry but i am not taking about you sorry once again if you are hurt

Comment: Nothing. It just seemed to me that they are not so difficult to get)

Comment: yah yah .. Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, which will prints the required URL's as per your requirement :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\NotBackedUp\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/nurnberg-dortmund-fNa2KmU4/')

# Locators for locating the required URL's
xpath = "//div[@id='odds-data-table']//tbody//tr"
rows = "//div[@id='odds-data-table']//tbody//tr/td[1]"
print("=> Required URL's is/are : ")
# Fetching & Printing the required URL's
for i in range(1, len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(rows)), 1):
    anchor = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath+"["+str(i)+"]/td[2]/a")
    if len(anchor) > 0:
        print(anchor[0].get_attribute('href'))
    else:
        a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='odds-data-table']//tbody//tr["+(str(i+1))+"]/td[1]//a[2]")
        if len(a) > 0:
            print(a[0].get_attribute('href'))

print('Done...')
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Hi @m0nte-cr1st0, check my answer and let me know it is helpful or not?

Comment: This is cool. But there is one nuance.
1. Some urls lead to the main page of the bookmaker, and not to the match page (asianodds, bet-at-home f.e.). 2. Some bookmakers not In list (1xbet, bethard etc). 3. Some url leads both to the main page of the bookmaker and to the event (bet365 f.e.).

Comment: I think the reason is because there are no links for some data that is displayed, you can check it by mouse-hovering on it manually.

Comment: For example, check for `1xBet` data `8.30` is not a link. It is some static text that is getting displayed from somewhere...

Comment: Oh, I did not think that the link to the event can be hidden in the coefficient)

Comment: Still, it seems to me that all the data comes from the events (1xbet too), but apparently it’s impossible to get links to these events ....

Comment: How do you think?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. We can print that data if we want to but find the link to that book mark is difficult...

Comment: difficult or impossible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187940/discussion-between-ali-cse-and-m0nte-cr1st0).